# Android error when searching SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my first post in here so let me know if you need anymore details.

I'm trying to search a SQLite database and load the data onto a screen and keep getting the following error from my logCat:

```
06-10 20:44:22.838: E/Trace(875): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-10 20:44:24.627: I/Choreographer(875): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-10 20:44:24.727: D/gralloc_goldfish(875): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-10 20:44:26.956: D/AndroidRuntime(875): Shutting down VM
06-10 20:44:26.956: W/dalvikvm(875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.findCountry(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:331)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.Core.searchDatabase(Core.java:64)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.HomeScreen$1.onClick(HomeScreen.java:39)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-10 20:44:27.006: E/AndroidRuntime(875):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 20:44:32.236: I/Process(875): Sending signal. PID: 875 SIG: 9
06-10 20:44:34.827: D/gralloc_goldfish(892): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

I have the following four main classes:
HomeScreen:

```
package com.Jamie.dosanddonts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    Core myCore;
    DosAndDontsDbAdapter myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.myDb = new DosAndDontsDbAdapter(this);
        this.myCore = new Core(myDb);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        Button france = null,germany = null,italy = null,spain = null,unitedKingdom = null;

        final Button buttons[] = {france, germany, italy, spain, unitedKingdom};
        int ids[] = {R.id.France,R.id.Germany,R.id.Italy,R.id.Spain,R.id.United_Kingdom};

        for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
        {
            buttons[i]=(Button) findViewById(ids[i]);
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        

        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataScreen.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);
                //int temp = v.getId();
                myCore.searchDatabase("Germany");           

            }
        }); 

    }}

}
```

DataScreen:

```
package com.Jamie.dosanddonts;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

public class DataScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_screen);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        Button homeButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Country_name);
        textView.setText("help");
        homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.data_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

DosAndDontsDbAdapter:

```
package com.Jamie.dosanddonts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DosAndDontsDbAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "dosAndDonts";

    private static final String COUNTRY = "Country name";
    private static final String INDICATOR = "Indicator";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

    public DosAndDontsDbAdapter(Context context) {
        super(null, DATABASE_TABLE, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + COUNTRY
                + " TEXT, " + INDICATOR + " TEXT, " + DESCRIPTION
                + " TEXT);");

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Shake hands when you greet someone.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do say 'bonjour' or 'bonsoir'.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Flowers should be given in odd numbers but not 13.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always smile");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always arrive on time for dinner.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating Do not rest your elbows on the table.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Don't refer to someone by their first name unless you are a close friend.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never offer cheap wine.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not begin eating until the hostess says 'bon appetit' ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "France");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not cut salad with a knife and fork. Fold the lettuce on to your fork. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();


        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Shake hands when greeting and leaving someone.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When you have finished eating lay your knide and fork parallel across your plate.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When in a pub pay for a round of drinks for everyone in your group.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating The fork is held tines down so food is scooped on to the back of the fork.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);

        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating, Table manners are Continental.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never get in their personal space.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "It's inapropriate to ask personal questions.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "They'll become unconfortalbe if engage in prolonged eye contact.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When eating don't rest your elbows on the table.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "United_Kingdom");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "DON'T make the V for victory sign with your palm facing yourself.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();


        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When greeting The usual handshake with direct eye contact.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Have calling card made.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you bring wine, make sure it is a good vintage.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you are invited to a meal, bring gift-wrapped such as wine or chocolates. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Table manners are Continental.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never give your business card in lieu of a calling card in a social situation.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give chrysanthemums as they are used at funerals.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not keep your hands in your lap during the meal.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give red flowers as they indicate secrecy. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Italy");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give yellow flowers as they indicate jealousy.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();

        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "A quick, firm handshake is the traditional greeting.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Titles are very important and denote respect.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When entering a room, shake hands with everyone individually.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Yellow roses or tea roses are always well received. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you bring wine, it should be imported.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not give lilies or chrysanthemums as they are used at funerals. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never arrive early, aslways on time.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not begin eating until the hostess starts.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not rest your elbows on the table.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Germany");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not cut lettuce in a salad. Fold it using your knife and fork.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();


        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Many men use a two-handed shake.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always bring a gift to someones house.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Always keep your hands visible when eating.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Use utensils to eat most food.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Do");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "If you have not finished eating, cross your knife and fork on your plate.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not begin eating until the hostess starts.  ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Do not get up until the guest of honour does. ");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Never toast first always allow the host to.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "When at dinner don't sit unless invited to do so.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        cv.put(COUNTRY, "Spain");
        cv.put(INDICATOR, "Dont");
        cv.put(DESCRIPTION, "Don't go bare cheasted anywhere other than the beach or poolside.");
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, COUNTRY, cv);
        cv.clear();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     Country findCountry(String country)
       {
        int index = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        List <DosAndDonts> dosNDonts = new ArrayList <DosAndDonts>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COUNTRY,
                INDICATOR, DESCRIPTION }, COUNTRY + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(country) }, null, null, null, null);

        Country returnedCountry = new Country();
        returnedCountry.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        do
        {

            dosNDonts.add(new DosAndDonts(cursor.getString(index + 1),
                        cursor.getString(index + 2)));


            index = index + 3;
            //returnedCountry.setCountryDosAndDonts(countryDosAndDonts)

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        returnedCountry.setCountryDosAndDonts(dosNDonts);


       //Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("FIND "+country+" as _id from "+DATABASE_TABLE,new String [] {});

        return returnedCountry;
       }


}
```

Core:

```
package com.Jamie.dosanddonts;

import java.util.List;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Core {

    private DosAndDontsDbAdapter myDosAndDontsDbAdapter;
    private TextView temp;
    private Country currentCountry;

    public Core(DosAndDontsDbAdapter myDb) {

        myDosAndDontsDbAdapter = myDb;

    }

    public Core() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void displayResult() 
    {
        TextView country = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Country_name);
        TextView do1 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do1);
        TextView do2 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do2);
        TextView do3 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do3);
        TextView do4 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do4);
        TextView do5 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Do5);
        TextView dont1 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont1);
        TextView dont2 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont2);
        TextView dont3 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont3);
        TextView dont4 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont4);
        TextView dont5 = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Dont5);

        TextView dos[] = { do1, do2, do3, do4, do5 };
        TextView donts[] = { dont1, dont2, dont3, dont4, dont5 };

        int doCounter = 0;
        int dontCounter = 0;
        int index = 0;
        List <DosAndDonts> dosNDonts = currentCountry.getCountryDosAndDonts(); 

        country.setText(currentCountry.getName());

        while (index < dosNDonts.size())
        {
            if (dosNDonts.get(index).getIndicator().equals("Do"))
            {
                dos[doCounter].setText(dosNDonts.get(index).getDescription());
                doCounter++;
            } 
            else 
            {
                donts[dontCounter].setText(dosNDonts.`enter code here`get(index).getDescription());
                dontCounter++;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    public void searchDatabase(String searchedCountry) {
        currentCountry = myDosAndDontsDbAdapter.findCountry(searchedCountry);
        //TextView country = (TextView) temp.findViewById(R.id.Country_name);
        //country.setText(searchedCountry);
        this.displayResult();
    }

}

enter code here
```

I have passed the argument "Germany" to try and locate the error further but with no luck. So the user selects a country on the homeScreen this then calls for the core class to search the database for that countries information and load it onto the dataScreen, when I remove the search database code the app moves between screens fine but with the search database code the app loads the home screen but then displays the logCat errors as soon as I click on a country, any help would be great.

Hi Guys

Thanks for your answers, so I have made the changes that being not to pass the argument as null on the adapter class and changing the do while to a while, but now I'm getting the following errors in logCat:

06-11 20:23:06.520: D/gralloc_goldfish(1268): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-11 20:23:10.620: I/Choreographer(1268): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-11 20:23:15.629: D/AndroidRuntime(1268): Shutting down VM
06-11 20:23:15.629: W/dalvikvm(1268): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268): java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.onCreate(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:33)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.DosAndDontsDbAdapter.findCountry(DosAndDontsDbAdapter.java:331)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.Core.searchDatabase(Core.java:64)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.Jamie.dosanddonts.HomeScreen$1.onClick(HomeScreen.java:39)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-11 20:23:15.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1268):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 20:23:16.689: D/dalvikvm(1268): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 10% free 2618K/2900K, paused 9ms+47ms, total 540ms

I have removed the button assignments using the for loop and replaced with a single button Germany and tried that and I still get the same errors in logCat, any ideas guy.

Kind regards chapinch

Answer (score 1):

Please don't pass `null` as the first parameter when you chain to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor. Instead, please pass the `Context` that you were given in your own constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You do not call cursor.moveToFirst(), so your first attempt at using the cursor tries to access the row -1. One alternative would be changing the do-while loop to a while loop:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{

        dosNDonts.add(new DosAndDonts(cursor.getString(index + 1),
                    cursor.getString(index + 2)));


        index = index + 3;
        //returnedCountry.setCountryDosAndDonts(countryDosAndDonts)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare is correct, the `NullPointerException` is a result of you calling super(null ... ) instead of passing through the context you're given.

This is why:

```
// mContext is null
224 db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(mName, mEnableWriteAheadLogging ?
225 Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING : 0,
226 mFactory, mErrorHandler);
```